# Could not set Native Handle Error Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm in the middle of training my net on tensorflow and I get this error at some part of the training process, though I can not tell exactly what is causing it because it will always happen at a seemingly random training sample at a more or less random epoch of training. I'm at my wits end with this and would like it if someone could shed light on it below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1361, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
 File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _run_fn
target_list, status, run_metadata)
 File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
  c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not set native handle, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_conv_ops.cc:652
     [[Node: SRGAN_g/Conv4_4/Conv2D = _MklConv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](SRGAN_g/pixelshufflerx2/1/4/Relu, SRGAN_g/Conv4/W_conv2d/read, SRGAN_g/pixelshufflerx2/1/4/Relu:1, DMT/_132)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 289, in <module>
    train()
File "main.py", line 149, in train
    errM, _ = sess.run([mse_loss, g_optim_init], {t_image: b_imgs_96, t_target_image: b_imgs_384})
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
options, run_metadata)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not set native handle, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_conv_ops.cc:652
     [[Node: SRGAN_g/Conv4_4/Conv2D = _MklConv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](SRGAN_g/pixelshufflerx2/1/4/Relu, SRGAN_g/Conv4/W_conv2d/read, SRGAN_g/pixelshufflerx2/1/4/Relu:1, DMT/_132)]]

Caused by op 'SRGAN_g/Conv4_4/Conv2D', defined at:
 File "main.py", line 289, in <module>
    train()
 File "main.py", line 53, in train
    net_g = SRGAN_g(t_image, is_train=True, reuse=False)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/srgan-master_TF/model.py", line 51, in SRGAN_g
    recursive_layers[i] = Conv2dReuse(recursive_layers[i], 256, (3, 3), (1, 1), act=None, padding='SAME', W_init=w_init, name='n256s1/2/%s' %i, group = "Conv4")
    File "/global/home/hpc4142/srgan-master_TF/nu_layers.py", line 461, in Conv2dReuse
group = group)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/srgan-master_TF/nu_layers.py", line 270, in __init__
self.outputs = act( tf.nn.conv2d(self.inputs, W, strides=strides, padding=padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu=use_cudnn_on_gpu, data_format=data_format) + b )
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 631, in conv2d
data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
  File "/global/home/hpc4142/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

AbortedError (see above for traceback): Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not set native handle, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_conv_ops.cc:652
[[Node: SRGAN_g/Conv4_4/Conv2D = _MklConv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](SRGAN_g/pixelshufflerx2/1/4/Relu, SRGAN_g/Conv4/W_conv2d/read, SRGAN_g/pixelshufflerx2/1/4/Relu:1, DMT/_132)]]
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same problem